# Bad interaction between line-height and border-width breaks vertical rhythm - can they be reconciled?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, grid-layout

I'm trying to implement a baseline/vertical rhythm on a responsive site. Top and bottom borders on table cells are causing me trouble. I have a minimal version of the problem here:

http://codepen.io/bakert/pen/akZWXE

If you set the border on th/td to 0 the vertical grid is respected from top to bottom and the text in both columns lines up. If you set the border to 0.0625em/1px/anything and scroll down below the table you will see that the columns are now out of whack. The text in the table itself is also no longer respecting the vertical grid.

The problem is that line-height does not account for border-width. The two things are additive in determining the height of the `td`s. Ideally I'm looking for something like `box-sizing: border-box` but for line-height + border.

I could solve this by explicitly giving `th.bordered, td.bordered` a fractionally smaller `line-height` than `p` but that sounds pretty awful. Should I be setting my vertical rhythm using something other than `line-height`? A combination of `line-height` and margin and I then reduce the margin by the width of the border? I'm hoping there's something simpler than that!

Comment: Can you use box-shadow instead of border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  table {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 0 #ccc;
  }
  td {
    padding-right: 1em;
    width: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0 #ccc;
  }
```

**EDIT** - September 4th
Fix for background-color.
You can use border for  element and margin should move element below 1px up. So border on table would not create another line-height problem. But this can not be used on  elements.

```
  table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ccc;
  }
```

Comment: Ah, that is smart. Not quiiiiite as elegant as I dreamed of but a lot less fiddly than taking tiny fractions of the line-heights of everything with borders :) Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I have overflow-x: auto on the div containing the table and this cuts off the bottom box shadow. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean, but you can try to set inset box-shadow on table as well. I will modify the code in answer.

Comment: This solution create box-shadow inside table, so I think, there should be no problem with overflow.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Except ... the box-shadow on table disappears when the tr's or td's have a background color. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mvv6x9o7/  Any ideas?

Comment: There's some explanation of the cause here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400130/why-does-a-background-break-a-box-shadow-inset-effect

Comment: Answer was edited. Is new modification fine for your use?

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I ended up posting this as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315204/how-to-prevent-background-color-from-hiding-box-shadow/39315747 but your solution is shorter! :)