# How to prevent background-color from hiding box-shadow?

Tags: html, css, border, box-shadow

Adding a `background-color` to a `td` or `tr` hides the `box-shadow` on the parent table.

Minimal example:

```css
table {
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 0 blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0 blue;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #efe;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>box shadow border fine here</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>and here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td>but not with background-color</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am using `box-shadow` to fake borders on a table. I'm showing "top and left" on each `td` and "bottom and right" on the `table` itself to fill in the missing parts.

But if any `td` or `tr` in my table has a `background-color` (`.highlight`) the `box-shadow` coming from the `table` disappears.

(As to why I'm doing this, it's because I'm setting a vertical rhythm on the site which applies to text in tables also. If I use standard table borders and my standard line-height I break the vertical rhythm. Even if I want to imperfectly account for borders by changing the line-height I cannot because the text might wrap making my border adjustment to the line-height apply to every row of text instead of just once for the block of text.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit the background size to 1 px less than the total size. Use calc (100% - 1px) for this:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


table {
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 0 blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0 blue;
}

.highlight td {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, red);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.highlight td:last-child {
  background-size: calc(100% - 1px) 100%;
}
.highlight:last-child td {
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 1px);
}
.highlight:last-child td:last-child {
  background-size: calc(100% - 1px) calc(100% - 1px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>box shadow border fine here</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>and here</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td>but not with background-color</td>
    <td>(second cell to illustrate gap)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td>second row to illustrate gap</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Another way to get this result, playing with shadows on the td instead of the table:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


table {
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 0 blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0 blue;
}

td:last-child {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0 blue, inset -1px 0px 0 0 blue;
}

tr:last-child td {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0 blue, inset 0px -1px 0 0 blue;
}

tr:last-child td:last-child {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0 blue, inset -1px -1px 0 0 blue;
}

.highlight td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>box shadow border fine here</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>and here</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td>but not with background-color</td>
    <td>(second cell to illustrate gap)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td>second row to illustrate gap</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this leaves a little gap when there is more than one cell in a row or more than one row: https://jsfiddle.net/kdm47m0g/3/  Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited the snippet. It's a bit more complex now.

Comment: Also, I have included another solution that seemed too complex at first, but that now makes sense.

Comment: Oh, awesome, and with these x-child selectors I can probably get rid of the drop-shadow on the table and *only* have stuff on the tds which seems better than what I had before. Thanks!

Comment: Just applied it to my design. Glee! Thanks so much - my baseline is preserved!

Answer (score 2):

Use the box shadow without the any offset.
like this:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;

}

td {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px blue;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This is clever! But unfortunately leaves a little gap if there is more than one row or more than one cell in a row: https://jsfiddle.net/kdm47m0g/4/

Comment: Have a look at my edit. See it on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asimovwasright/kdm47m0g/5/

Comment: Thanks! Am I right in thinking the inner borders are now 2px whereas the outer borders are 1px? And the color of the borders is changed by the background color (although that may not matter in my case)? Maybe trying to fake borders with box-shadow is more pain than it is worth ... !

Comment: Yes, indeed the borders will add up to 2px where they are touching one another. The reason they change color is because they are shadow effects, which by nature have below 1 opacity, so they will change color a bit.